# Android facebook sdk share image

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to share image from my android app on facebook which I havent completed yet.I want to be sure if it shares image on facebook properly.I wrote the code to share image and i think it works well.But when I run my app facebook asks me if I accept my app to get my information it is well working so far.But just before sharePhoto... ı got this error The publish_actions permissions are missing.Does it mean I have to release my app to use facebook?Cant I share image using my admin or tester account of facebook? I just wanna know if my app shares image properly.ty
this is my code

```
permissionNeeds= Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    ShareApi.share(content, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your Facebook app is in Dev mode, not Public. And your facebook acc is in admin or tester list of Facebook app

Comment: How can I make my app developer mode

Answer (score 0):

You evidently must not be requesting the `share_photo` permission at login.  From your code snippet you're doing nothing with `permissionNeeds`.

You must call `setPublishPermissions` on your login button, or `logInWithPublishPermissions` if you're using the LoginManager, and pass in the list of permissions requested (which you have here called `permissionNeeds`).